# How to apply certain margin or padding to the id containing div if there is #link in URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

Case: When URL looks like **localhost/test.html#services** or getting to this page from another page with a link test.html#services

I need certain margin or padding to the div that contains id="services" from the top.

My Code:

```css
.navbar{
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:2;
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline-flex;
}

.container{
margin-top:4rem;
}

.container h1{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<section>
<div class="container">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut
<p> 

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut
<p> 

<div id="services">
<h1 class="text-danger">Our Services</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut
<p> 

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut
<p> 

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aliquam distinctio facere nisi ipsum, ab odit eaque ea nulla quibusdam! Id molestias odio deleniti praesentium. Provident nulla reprehenderit aut
<p> 
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: Provide your question with sample of code.